# actualizar dato con resultado de consulta mysql

Tags: mysql

agradezco su ayuda con la siguiente situacion, cuando la columna ctdnovedad tenga un mayor a 0,  la columna estadoruta debe quedar (entregadoconobservacion), en 0 debe actualizar estadoruta con (entregadosinnovedad)
intento con siguiente sentencia para me marca error 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `ztmpindicamabe2` SET `EstadoRuta`='A' WHERE (`ConsManifiesto`= a.ConsMan' at line 9

```
SELECT
a.ConsManifiesto,
a.SecManifiesto,
a.NumeroManifiesto,
a.ObsRuta,
a.CtdNovedad,
a.ObsNovedad,
a.EstadoRuta,
IF(a.CtdNovedad > 0,a.EstadoRuta,(UPDATE `ztmpindicamabe2` SET `EstadoRuta`='entregadosinnovedad' WHERE (`ConsManifiesto`= a.ConsManifiesto)))
FROM ztmpindicamabe2 AS a
WHERE a.CodigoRuta IN ('4004', '4009')
```

los datos que tengo en la imagen son
136659  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES   3   TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET  POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES  ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136660  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136661  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136662  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136663  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136664  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136665  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136666  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136667  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136668  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136669  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136670  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION
136671  300103350   173857  TEXCOMERCIAL BODEGA GUARNE RECHAZA 3 LMC46100WDAB0 LAVADORA AUT 16 KG MABE MET POR RAYON EN LAMINA UND SERA RETORNADA A CDR MANIZALES           ENTREGADO CON OBSERVACION

la tabla

```
ConsManifiesto  int 11  0   0   -1  0   0   0       0                   -1  0
SecManifiesto   varchar 15  0   -1  0   0   0   0       0       utf8    utf8_spanish2_ci        0   0
NumeroManifiesto    varchar 15  0   -1  0   0   0   0       0       utf8    utf8_spanish2_ci        0   0
ObsRuta text    0   0   -1  0   0   0   0       0       utf8    utf8_spanish2_ci        0   0
CtdNovedad  int 10  0   -1  0   0   0   0       0                   0   0
ObsNovedad  text    0   0   -1  0   0   0   0       0       utf8    utf8_spanish2_ci        0   0
EstadoNovedad   varchar 255 0   -1  0   0   0   0       0       utf8    utf8_spanish2_ci        0   0
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no podes tener un select con un update en el medio.. que intentaste hacer?

Comment: intento que cuando me lea un registro por ejemplo 136659 evalua si ctdnovedad es >0, si lo es el campo estadoruta coloque mensaje 'entregadoconobservacion', sino mensaje 'entregadosinnovedad'. y despues evalue el registro 136660 y hago lo mismo.

Comment: Pero eso se hace solo con un update.. para que tenes todo el select?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

requiero hacer una actualizacion a campo llamado obsruta,cuando se cumpla la condicion de columna ctdnovedad diferente de 0. hago la consulta para saber si ctd esta en 0 para el update. estuve leyendo y probando y lo resolvi con esta sentencia 'UPDATE ztmpindicamabe2 INNER JOIN ( SELECT a.ConsManifiesto,a.SecManifiesto,a.NumeroManifiesto,a.ObsRuta,a.CtdNovedad,a.ObsNovedad,a.EstadoRuta FROM ztmpindicamabe2 AS a WHERE a.CtdNovedad is NULL)tabla2 ON ztmpindicamabe2.ConsManifiesto = tabla2.ConsManifiesto SET ztmpindicamabe2.`EstadoRuta`='.ENTREGADO A SATISFACCION'

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).